# Добавить область для виджета внутрь поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Каким образом в WP можно добавить область для виджета прямо внутрь текста поста? Например, чтобы область всё время была после второго абзаца в статье.

Вставка виджета шорткодом не подходит, нужна именно область.

Есть идея сделать отдельный php файл с кодом области и подключать его после нужного абзаца но как это правильно написать я не представляю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этих целей существует хук-фильтр контента. Ниже приведён полный код небольшого плагина, который создаёт свой виджет, и выводит его на определённых страницах после втрого абзаца.

Код можно скопировать в файл `some-name.php` и поместить в папку `/wp-content/plugins/`, затем активировать плагин. Вместо кастомного виджета можно использовать любой системный.

Результат работы можно посмотреть на странице `http://test.kagg.eu/so572791/`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Widget in the post
 *
 * Plugin Name: Widget in Post
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-in-post/
 * Description: Shows widget as the second paragraph in the post.
 * Author: KAGG Design
 * Author URI: https://profiles.wordpress.org/kagg.eu/
 * Requires at least: 5.0
 * Tested up to: 5.4
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Stable tag: 1.0.0
 *
 * Text Domain: widget-in-post
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 *
 * @package widget-in-post
 * @author  KAGG Design
 */

/**
 * Class WIP_Widget
 */
class WIP_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * WIP_Widget constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'wip_widget',
            'WIP Widget Title',
            [ 'description' => 'WIP Widget description' ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Frontend.
     *
     * @param array $args     Arguments.
     * @param array $instance Instance.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Default Widget Title', 'wip-widget' );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title );

        echo wp_kses_post( $args['before_widget'] );
        if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'] );
        }
        echo wp_kses_post( '<strong>Some text to add via WIP Widget</strong>' );
        echo wp_kses_post( $args['after_widget'] );
    }

    /**
     * Backend.
     *
     * @param array $instance Instance.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Default Widget Title', 'wip-widget' );

        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_html( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>">
                <?php echo esc_html__( 'Title:', 'wip-widget' ); ?>
            </label>
            <input
                    class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_html( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"
                    name="<?php echo esc_html( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text"
                    value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Save widget settings.
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New settings.
     * @param array $old_instance Old settings.
     *
     * @return array
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance          = [];
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }
}

/**
 * The content filter.
 *
 * @param string $content Post content.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wip_the_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;

    $insert_after  = 2; // Paragraph number to insert widget after.
    $allowed_pages = [ 'so572791', 'some-other-page-slug' ]; // Pages to work.

    if ( ! isset( $post ) || ! in_array( $post->post_name, $allowed_pages, true ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    ob_start();
    the_widget( 'WIP_Widget' );
    $addon = ob_get_clean();

    $content_arr = explode( '</p>', $content );
    array_splice( $content_arr, $insert_after, 0, $addon );

    return implode( '</p>', $content_arr );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wip_the_content_filter' );

/**
 * Register widget.
 */
function register_wip_widget() {
    register_widget( 'WIP_Widget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_wip_widget' );
```

Comment: а где прописать сам код области для виджета?

Comment: Замените строку
    $addon = 'text to insert';
на то, что нужно. Т.е. в переменную $addon запишите html код вставки (виджета)

Comment: Так проблема в том, что мне надо вставлять не html код виджета, а PHP код области для виджета

Comment: Я расширил ответ и привёл работающий пример кода.