# Как использовать стандартное кастомное поле внутри the_content()?

Tags: wordpress

Создаю через WordPress UI страницу. Редактирую ее там же, добавляя, текстовый блок, список и галерею.

Вывожу это в `page.php`(условно) через функцию `the_content()`. Внизу редактора страницы предлагается меню для добавления кастомного поля, которое вывожу **перед** или **после** `the_content()`:

```
echo get_post_meta( page_id, custom_field_name, true )
```

Как вывести кастомное поле **внутри** `the_content()`, например, между текстовым блоком и списком?

Comment: Тут показано, как добавить в произвольное место внутри поста кодом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте шорткод и добавьте его в контент, а вывод шорткода будет ваше поле)

В контент:

*Какой-то текст [custom_field_name] и текст продолжается :)*

В `functions.php`:

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_field_name', 'show_custom_field_name' );
function custom_field_name() {
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field_name', true );
}
```

Comment: перед именем функции только добавьте show_, вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится)